# unable to load 64 bit dll

Tags: c++, windows, dll

I am using "LoadLibraryA()" for loading my dll. Here is the code for loading dll I used -

```
std::string m_sDllRegPath = "F:\\Releases\\SampleApp\\MyDll.dll";
m_hDll = LoadLibraryA(m_sDllRegPath.c_str());
```

But the problem is that value of m_hDll is always null, that it means it has failed to load the dll. A call to `GetLastError` returns 126.

But the same code works fine for 32 bit system. I don't know where is the problem.

Comment: MyDll.dll and exe are both 64bit?

Comment: Yes, both are in 64 bit system. Checked with dependency walker.

Comment: And when `LoadLibrary` fails, what does `GetLastError` tell you?

Comment: "You can't concatenate string like that" what is the problem if I do that in this way?

Comment: That string concatenation doesn't even compile in VS2012. Is this really your actual code?

Comment: Yes it is the actual code and it is in VS2010. And Load library returns 126 error code. Do you know the meaning of that?

Comment: Error 126 is `ERROR_MOD_NOT_FOUND` *The specified module could not be found*.

Comment: Can you please elaborate more?

Comment: Most likely then is that the module isn't where you think it is.... Or the string doesn't contain what you think it should...

Comment: @Naseef That string concatenation is not legal.  It will not compile, and if it does, the behavior is undefined.  Why not post (or even try) *legal* code?   Or simply do this: `LoadLibraryA("F:\\Releases\\SampleApp\\MyDll.dll");` and see if this works correctly.

Comment: As I told earlier this is the real code.

Comment: @Naseef - Just because it is the "real code" doesn't mean it isn't faulty.  Again, you cannot concatenate strings like that.  All you're doing is adding two pointer values.  If that code compiled, the behavior is undefined, simple as that.  If you want to know the real error (if there is an error), actually put the DLL name in the LoadLibraryA call and see if it works.

Comment: When Dll is loaded, all its dependent libraries are loaded as well. `ERROR_MOD_NOT_FOUND` may be reported if library dependencies cannot be resolved. (And, of course, your code is not compiled).

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie I have tried with your suggestions but no luck.

Comment: @Naseef - Then I suggest you update your question to include the new code.  Then we can eliminate the possibility that your code is faulty, and instead concentrate on environmental issues (i.e. DLL is not found, secondary DLL's cannot be found, etc.)

Comment: I already did @PaulMcKenzie

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Error code 126 is [`ERROR_MOD_NOT_FOUND`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/windows/desktop/ms681382.aspx#ERROR_MOD_NOT_FOUND):

> The specified module could not be found.

If there really is a DLL with the file name that you provide, then the explanation is that one of the DLL's dependencies is missing. Almost invariably this is because the C++ runtime that is required by the DLL is not present. Check the requirements of the DLL, and make sure that all required dependencies are correctly installed.

Comment: Process Monitor (available from the MS web site) is a useful tool for identifying missing dependencies, if the DLL is not properly documented.